# show alert on servlet redirect to another jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

i'm doing an final project about hibernate and jsp and servlet also database
my topic is making a recipe's web application

now, i want to register

i make this method to check the uname has already been used or not (this  method is work well, no error)

```
public boolean unameMember (String namaTabel,String uname)
{
    this.session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    ArrayList<Member> hasil = null;
    boolean uyey = true;
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from "+namaTabel);
    hasil = (ArrayList<Member>) q.list();
    for (Member m : hasil) 
    {
        if(m.getIdMember().equals(uname))
            uyey=false;
    }
    session.close();

    return uyey;
}
```

this is the register.jsp 's form

```
<form action="MemberServlet" method="post" id="regform">


                    <div class="form" >

                        <div class="form_row">

                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="id_member" required />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pw"  required />
                        </div> 


                        </div> 

                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nama" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Alamat:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="alamat" required/>
                        </div>




                        <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and now here's the problem in the MemberServlet.java

```
String id_member = request.getParameter("id_member");
    String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
    String nama = request.getParameter("nama");
    String alamat = request.getParameter("alamat");
    DataAkses da = new DataAkses();
try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

            if (da.unameMember("Member", nama)) {
                da.addMember(id_member, pw, nama, alamat);

                out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                out.println("alert('You can sign in with your new account');");
                out.println("</script>");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").include(request, response);
            } else {
                out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                out.println("alert('User or password incorrect');");
                out.println("location='register.jsp';");
                out.println("</script>");
            }  } catch (Exception e) {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("</b>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<center>");
        out.println("<h1>haha ga bisa </h1>");
        out.println("</center>");
        out.println("</body>");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if i want to add member with a different uname it's work well
otherwise
it always shows the "haha ga bisa" in the catch exception

help me please

Comment: Can you please provide your error stack trace from console ?

Comment: how to show error stack trace ? sorry i'm a beginner in programming

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong on so many levels I feel you would be better taking an alternative approach. Essentially, check the details and if an error then return back to the register page, showing an error message as appropriate. Otherwise, forward to another page.

Roughly this will look like:

Form handler:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    String nextPage;

    if(problemWithDetails){
        nextPage = "register.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid Details");
    }
    else{
        nextPage = "success.jsp";
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher(nextPage).forward(request, response);
}
```

register.jsp

```
<!-- Import JSTL tag library >
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>   
<html>

    <!-- Use JSTL to check for the error message we set on form submission if invalid data -->
    <c:if test="${not empty errorMessage}">
        There was an error: ${errorMessage}.
    </c:if>

    <form action="MemberServlet" method="post" id="regform">

        <!-- form as before -->

    </form>
</html>
```